# deleting sheets error "subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets named tab 1 and tab 2. 
I am creating sheets based on the entries in tab 2 using below:

```
Sub copyeachrowtosheets()

Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer

Dim z As String

Dim y As Integer

Dim x As String

Dim h As Worksheet

Dim k As Integer

Dim l As String

Dim m As String

i = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

y = 2

For j = 1 To (i - 1)

z = "A" & y

x = "M" & y

k = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

m = "B" & y

l = Sheets(2).Range(m).Value

Set h = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(k))

h.Name = l

Sheets(2).Range("A1:M1").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

y = y + 1

Next j

End Sub

now if i want to delete all the created sheets using vba, i made the below:

Sub deletesheetsspecific()

Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer

'Dim x As Integer

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    For j = 1 To i

    Dim k As String

    k = VBA.left(Sheets(j).Name, 3)

        If k <> "tab" Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(j).delete

        End If

    Next j

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

it simply deletes a random few sheets, then gives the error "run-time error: subscript out of range" at line that says "k = VBA.left(Sheets(j).Name, 3)". if i click to run again, it deletes a few more sheets then same error.

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here please?

Comment: loop through the sheets backwards: `For j = i To 1 step -1`

Comment: worked! could you kindly explain what does this do please?

Comment: As you are deleting sheets the index number changes to match the new count but j does not and eventually you get to a large j than there are sheets left.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count` is evaluated before you start deleting things.  Once you delete a worksheet, the count does down. The end of your loop doesn't.

Comment: oh my! i though value of j changes as well when you go through a loop. could i used a counter instead of j then? like o=1, then at the end like o = o+1?

Comment: no then `o` would be larger.  Just loop from the end when deleting.

Comment: cool thanx dude!

Comment: @Comintern are you sure? i thought once you assign a number to a variable it stays, and as it was assigned before the loop, its value would not change based on the fact that that line was already compiled. am i wrong here?

Comment: @P.MAJ: The variable being assigned a value in advance is exactly the problem here. The code in the post is the equivalent of cutting off the branch you're standing on - if you capture the number of sheets, and then start deleting them, the captured variable does not get reduced, and at some point you have a higher number in the variable than you do sheets in the workbook.

Comment: ["The expressions <start-value>, <end-value>, and <step-increment> are evaluated ***once***, in order, and prior to any of the following computations."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157012.aspx) My emphasis.

Comment: @Ken nice one dude!!! oh man i love stackoverflow, very helpful people everytime! now i know what i did wrong. many many thanks Ken. so am i right to assume step -1 reduces the value of i in each loop, right?

Comment: @P.MAJ: Yes. And going downward when you delete sheets reduces the bounds of the loop at the same time you're reducing the number of sheets, which means you can't go off the end. (As a note: Using the debugger to step through the code for issues like this is very educational - you can learn a lot by watching what the code is doing.)